# Is it possible to Generate a Master Shape Key from different objects?

Tags: shape-keys

I have Two objects in the scene, Each One Of Them has a shape key, is there a way to generate a master shape key to Control Both of the shape keys in those Objects at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you select one of the shape key value you just need to right click on this one > Copy as new driver, then go to the other object> shape key value > Right click Paste driver